# Populating dictionary with list if statement

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I do not understand how the dictionary "count" is being being populated and referenced by 'List'.

Specifically, why do items in the list ('List') get added to the dictionary ('count') with the "if item in count" statement?

The 'count' dictionary is empty to begin with and there is no 'append' function.

Here is the python function:

```
def countDuplicates(List):
    count = {}
    for item in List:
        if item in count:
            count[item] += 1
        else:
            count[item] = 1
    return count

print(countDuplicates([1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5]))
```

output: `{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}`

Comment: Is there something wrong with this code? Is this your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You might also want to invest some time in working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I think the question is clear. The 2nd paragraph asks what `in` does, and the 3rd paragraph asks how to add stuff to a `dict` without `append`.

Comment: Python has the in-built [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to achieve the same task

Answer (score 2):

you can run your code by hand to see how it works

```
count = {} // empty dict
```

iterating through list first element is 1 it checks the dict in this line to see is this element added to the dict before

```
if item in count:
```

it's not in the count so it puts the element to the list and makes its value 1 in this line

```
 count[item] = 1 //This appends the item to the dict as a key and puts value of 1
```

count becomes

```
count ={{1:1}}
```

then it iterates through the next element witch is 2 same story count becomes

```
count={{1:1},{2:1}}
```

next item is 4

```
count = {{1:1},{2:1},{4,1}}
```

next item is 2 in this case we have 2 in our dict so it increases it's value by 1 in this line

```
     count[item] += 1
```

count becomes

```
count = {{1:1},{2:2},{4,1}}
```

and it continues until the list is finished

Comment: Thanks @Alper First Kaya! This is exactly the explanation/walk-through I was looking for!

Comment: What I want to tell you is that you're not alone :P `from collections import Counter; duplicates = Counter([1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5])` https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Thanks @slackmart. The 'collections' library would definitely work in this case as well. I posted this question to understand the assignment of items from a list into a dictionary with an if statement. Definitely fundamental, but a worthwhile programming lesson.

Answer (score 1):

This is why it checks `if item in count`, which will fail if this is the first time you are seeing the count (since it won't be defined in the dictionary yet).

In that case, it will define it using `count[item] = 1`.

The next time the count is seen, it will already have been defined (as 1), so you can increment it using `count[item] += 1`, i.e. `count[item] = count[item] + 1`, i.e. `count[item] = 1 + 1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense! The "if item in count" will fail the first time and assign the [count] with an 'item' from List with 'else: count[item]' for the first time a unique item from List is first encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, why do items in the list ('List') get added to the dictionary ('count') with the "if item in count" statement?

```
`checking if the element already added in to dictionary, if existing increment the value associated with item.
Example:
[1,2,4,3,2,2,5]
dict[item]  = 1  value is '1'--> Else block, key '1'(item) is not there in the dict, add to and increment the occurrence by '1'
```

when the element in list[1,2,4,3,2,2,5] is already present in the dict
count[item] += 1 --> increment the occurrence against each item`

=================

The 'count' dictionary is empty to begin with and there is no 'append' function.

```
append functionality not supported for empty dict and can be achieved by 
count[item] += 1
```